# Como concateno más datos a un listview en tiempo de ejecución en xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarinforms

Quiero hacer un listview paginado y para hacerlo quiero que al hacer el scroll carguen más resultados. Para ello se me ha ocurrido hacer un método que me carga unos reultados y que al hacer el scroll me agregue más datos pero cuando se agregan más datos entra en un bucle infinito. Este es el código del viewmodel  que uso :

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private  ObservableCollection<data> items;

        public ListView Lista { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<data> Items { get => items; set 
            { items = value;NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Items)); } }

        public MainViewModel(ListView l)
        {
            Lista = l;

            Lista.Scrolled += Lista_Scrolled;

            Items = new ObservableCollection<data>();


             datos();

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private async void Lista_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
        {

            await agregar();
        }




        private async Task datos()
        {


            await Task.Run(() => {


                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ar", dr = "df" });
                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ar", dr = "df" });

                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ar", dr = "df" });
                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ar", dr = "df" });
                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ar", dr = "df" });
                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ar", dr = "df" });
                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "xx", dr = "df" });
                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "xx", dr = "df" });
                Items.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ff", dr = "df" });

            });


            Lista.ItemsSource = Items;


        }

        private async Task agregar()
        {

            ObservableCollection<data> aux = Items;

            Items.Clear();

            await Task.Run(()=> {

                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ff", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "rr", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "rr", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "rr", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ff", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ff", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "ff", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "hh", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "hh", dr = "df" });
                aux.Add(new App51.data { ar = "hh", dr = "df" });

            });

            Items = aux;

            Lista.ItemsSource = Items;
        }


        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
        }

    }
```

El código se ejecuta bien pero cuando se llama al método agregar entra en un bucle como si estuviera en un while y se llama el método agregar una y otra vez???

Answer (score 0):

Tengo unas correcciones para realizar sobre `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
1- ObservableCollection ya hereda de dicha Interface lo cual no es necesario colocar sobre esa colección la interface.
2-Cuando en el metodo que ejecuta el evento, usas `CallerMember`, este ya infiere quien lo llama, no hace falta pasarle `nameof(propiedad)`.
3-Cuando vas agregando elementos a la coleccion, el ListView deberia interpretar que la coleccion tiene nuevos elementos o cambios y mostrarlos.
4-El Listview tiene la propiedad CachingStrategy="" para que mejore el rendimiento del mismo. Te dejo la doc para que la veas y uses la que mejor creas que se adecue a tu necesidad.
5-Tenes el metodo `agregar` sobre un Evento scroller que seguramente se ejecuta muchas veces cuando moves un poco el listview y eso hace parecer que es infinito.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance

```
public ObservableCollection<data> Items 
{
      get => items; 
      set 
            { 
              if(items == value)
                 return;

              items = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Items); 
            } 
}
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
}
```